# Changing bulb in a pinhole downlight

Tags: light-fixture, bulb

I recently moved in to a flat and need to replace some blown bulbs. From internet searches, the fittings appear to be "fixed pinhole downlights", but I cannot find any details on how to remove the cover to change the bulb.

The fittings look like this:

[image: ceiling light with round plastic cover, elongated hole for light, and recessed bulb]

The slot is too narrow to fit the bulb through, and twisting / sliding the cover does nothing. Pulling downwards causes the whole fitting (including the bulb) to move; I dare not pull too much in case this isn't the right way to remove it and I damage something or make it difficult to put back.

Comment: I would suspect, but don't KNOW, that the whole fitting pulling down is fine, and it will be in a "can" held by springs (like the trim rings on other can lights) that will stop after it pulls down a few inches.

Comment: There are so many of these on the market but all operate pretty much the same.  Like Ecnerwal stated, the trim and bulb should just pull down. It could have clips that hold it in place and could be pulled all the way out of the can and have a plug of screw terminal connecting it to the can...  You're gonna have to experiment  with this..... just take it slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suspected by Ecnerwal and JACK, pulling down with moderate force eventually released the whole fitting, which was being held in place with sprung fins. It did result in a bit of the ceiling plaster coming down as dust in the process, but it seems to be the way it is expected to work. Pushing back up caused it to latch back in place.